# Making a SOAP WebService request after a WebMethod response has been sent

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

We're doing some async communication with .NET web services, and we need a way to fire off a request from the server back to the client, but only after the initial request has completed (the client has received the HTTP 200).

Ideally we're looking for some handler or event which is called when a WebMethod's response has been flushed back to the caller.

We've looked at `SoapExtension`, e.g. `SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize`, but think that happens too early (the response hasn't been sent out to the client yet).

We've considered just starting up a new thread, but we can't guarantee this will actually happen after the rest of the web method is executed. Does anyone know a better solution?